# Processing log files, distribute work among worker threads, to find a simple sum

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to distribute work among threads.  Load parts of a log file and then distribute the work to process parts of the file.

In my simple example, I wrote 800,000 lines of data and had a number in each line.  And then I sum the number.

When I run this example, I get totals that are slightly off.  Do you see in this threading code where threads might not complete properly and hence won't total the numbers?

```
public void process() {
    final String d = FILE;
    FileInputStream stream = null;
    try {                        
        stream = new FileInputStream(d);
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));            
        String data = "";                                                                       
        do {                
            final Stack<List<String>> allWork = new Stack<List<String>>();
            final Stack<ParserWorkerAtLineThread> threadPool = new Stack<ParserWorkerAtLineThread>();
            do {
                if (data != null) {
                    final List<String> currentWorkToDo = new ArrayList<String>();
                    do {
                        data = reader.readLine();
                        if (data != null) {     
                            currentWorkToDo.add(data);                        
                        } // End of the if //
                    } while(data != null && (currentWorkToDo.size() < thresholdLinesToAdd));
                    // Hand out future work                        
                    allWork.push(currentWorkToDo);
                } // End of the if //
            } while(data != null && (allWork.size() < numberOfThreadsAllowedInPool));                                      
            // Process the lines from the work to do //                 
            // Hand out the work
            for (final List<String> theCurrentTaskWork : allWork) {
                final ParserWorkerAtLineThread t = new ParserWorkerAtLineThread();
                t.data = theCurrentTaskWork;
                threadPool.push(t);
            }                                          
            for (final Thread workerAboutToDoWork : threadPool) {
                workerAboutToDoWork.start();
                System.out.println("   -> Starting my work... My name is : " + workerAboutToDoWork.getName());
            } // End of the for //                
            // Waiting on threads to finish //    
            System.out.println("Waiting for all work to complete ... ");                    
            for (final Thread waiting : threadPool) {
                waiting.join();
            } // End of the for //                                   
            System.out.println("Done waiting ... ");

        } while(data != null); // End of outer parse file loop //

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } // End of the stream //
    } // End of the try - catch  finally  //  


}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it would faster and simpler if it were single threaded.  Did you try that first?  You bug could be in how you add the total (which you don't show)

Comment: Where is the thread class code?

Comment: Are you certain that `thresholdLinesToAdd * numberOfThreadsAllowedInPool` is larger than the number of lines you expect to process?  That would be one possible cause.

Comment: I agree that this is quite likely to be faster in a single thread, but if your goal is to learn how to do it using multiple threads I'd suggest you look at the Executors and AtomicInteger classes.

Comment: No, it ran faster with the threads.  And I am just experimenting with threading.

Comment: Atomic Integer may be the issue.

Comment: Also, this is simple map/reduce?

Comment: Please show ParserWorkerAtLineThread code and how you sum the values produced by teh threads as well.

Answer (score 0):

While you're at it, why not use a bounded BlockingQueue (ArrayBlockingQueue) of size thresholdLinesToAdd. This would be your producer code where you read the lines and use the method put on that queue to block until space is available.

As Chris mentionned before, use the Executors.newFixedThreadPool() to submit your work items on it. Your consumers would call take() to block until an element is available.

This is not a map/reduce. If you wanted a map/reduce, you would need another queue in the mix where you would publish keys to it. As an example, if you were to count the number of INFO and DEBUG occurances in your logs, your mapper would queue the extracted words every time it encounters it. The reducer would dequeue the mapper's output and increment the counter of each words. The result of your reducer would the word count for DEBUG and INFO.